# Setup AWS Data Pipeline on long running EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

If I want to have long running EMR cluster and after that I want to setup Data Pipeline doing something on that cluster, how I can do it?

I must install Task Runner on this EMR cluster? Or maybe Task Runner will be preinstalled ? Or maybe there is other simple way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task Runner does not come pre-installed in EMR. It has to be configured manually, follow these [steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-user-managed.html) to install Task Runner in EMR cluster.

On starting the Task Runner process, provide a name for the `--workerGroup`. This name will be the identifier for this EMR cluster and can be used for the `WorkerGroup` field in Datapipeline activities.

Comment: Is it possible to do it by Bootstrap Action?

Comment: Yes, You can add those steps as a script and use that for bootstrap action.

Comment: Could You post your bootstrap doing this? I have WAITING_FOR_RUNNER  status.

Comment: Why WAITING_FOR_RUNNER? Did you pass a non-task runner EMR as worker group?

Comment: Bootstrap action runs on all nodes, doesn't it? Task Runner needs to be installed only on master